# The view ProductCreateView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-generic-views

How to redirect to another page from `def form_valid(self):` inside a generic `FormView`.

I know I should do something like `Super(className, self).form_valid(form):` but this will never redirect to a dynamic link, but will only go to the `success URL`

Here is my code :

```py
class ProductCreateView(FormView):
    form_class = ProductCreateForm
    template_name = 'back_office/product_create_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('product_recipe_wrapper')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        category = Category.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        image = form.cleaned_data['image']
        big_size = form.cleaned_data['big_size']
        mid_size = form.cleaned_data['mid_size']
        small_size = form.cleaned_data['small_size']
        new_product = Product.objects.create(category=category, name=name, image=image)
        big_size_object = ProductSize.objects.create(product=new_product, size=Size.objects.get(id=1),
                                                     sell_price=big_size)
        mid_size_object = ProductSize.objects.create(product=new_product, size=Size.objects.get(id=2),
                                                     sell_price=mid_size)
        small_size_object = ProductSize.objects.create(product=new_product, size=Size.objects.get(id=3),
                                                       sell_price=small_size)
        if small_size_object.sell_price != 0:
            return reverse_lazy('product_small_recipe', args=[small_size_object.id])

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductCreateView, self).get_context_data()
        context['category'] = Category.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return context
```

Comment: If you return `super().form_valid(form)`, then you can override the `get_success_url` method instead of `success_url` and change the URL dynamically. However in this case, you are using `small_size_object.id`, so it's probably clearer to return the redirect inside the `form_valid` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `form_valid` method needs to return a response. The error message *It returned None instead* means that the method didn't return anything at all. In the code above, that would happen when `small_size_object.sell_price == 0:`.

Next, you can't do `return reverse_lazy(...)`, because the method needs to return a *response*, not a URL. If you want to redirect, you can use `HttpResponseRedirect`, for example:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class ProductCreateView(FormView):
    ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('product_small_recipe', args=[small_size_object.id]))
```

Note you can use `reverse` here instead of `reverse_lazy` because you're inside a method.

You can simplify the code by using the `redirect` shortcut.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class ProductCreateView(FormView):
    ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...
        return redirect('product_small_recipe', small_size_object.id)
```